# Custom bytecode logs data but doesn't return it on eth_call, why not?

Tags: json-rpc, bytecode, eth-call

I'm creating custom bytecode for a project

```
0x4160005260206000a0
// OP-Codes
// COINBASE
// PUSH1 0x00
// MSTORE
// PUSH1 0x20
// PUSH1 0x20
// LOG0
```

when the above is created, the transaction receipt contains the following data in its logs `0x00000000000000000000000085f7c2480b66ca340e9f2a534dbf8b660137889f`

but for some reason when I try the same but with the return opcode `f3`,

```
0x4160005260206000f3
// OP-Codes
// COINBASE
// PUSH1 0x00
// MSTORE
// PUSH1 0x20
// PUSH1 0x20
// RETURN
```

but it returns

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 8,
    "result": "0x"
}
```

When I expect

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 8,
    "result": "0x00000000000000000000000085f7c2480b66ca340e9f2a534dbf8b660137889f"
}
```

---

The exact call looks like this

```
// to create contract
{
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "method":"eth_sendTransaction",
    "params": [
        {
            "from": "{{Account1}}",
            "data": "0x4160005260206000f3"
        }
    ],
    "id": 1
}
> response
{
   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   "id": 1,
   "result": "0xe81e280e6fa833e9f65b1d933fcb2183b7241f46e52afe7ff1501759d01d52ed"
}

// To get the transaction receipt
{
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "method":"eth_getTransactionReceipt",
    "params": [
        "0xe81e280e6fa833e9f65b1d933fcb2183b7241f46e52afe7ff1501759d01d52ed"
    ],
    "id": 1
}

> response
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "result": {
        "blockHash": "0x40cce6d74ceafaf0dd005a83adc614fc6bbc438ad4bcadb014f3cb2ccdd0b775",
        "blockNumber": "0xd1",
        "contractAddress": "0xee408b2d602d94e06a9d0241cc9dc0092eed1d53",
        "cumulativeGasUsed": "0xe891",
        "from": "0x85f7c2480b66ca340e9f2a534dbf8b660137889f",
        "gasUsed": "0xe891",
        "logs": [],
        "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "status": "0x1",
        "to": null,
        "transactionHash": "0xe81e280e6fa833e9f65b1d933fcb2183b7241f46e52afe7ff1501759d01d52ed",
        "transactionIndex": "0x0"
    }
}

// Finally making the call
{
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "method":"eth_call",
    "params": [{
        "from": "{{Account1}}",
        "to": "0xee408b2d602d94e06a9d0241cc9dc0092eed1d53"
    }, "latest"],
    "id": 1
}

> response
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "result": "0x"
}
```

The above calls were made using postman to my local development geth blockchain in JSON RPC API mode.

Comment: Actually to deploy a contract you have to execute a constructor that returns the bytecode to be deployed, just sending the bytecode wont work. After deploying you can check the runtime bytecode with [web3.eth.getCode](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth.html#getcode). The bytecode with return should be deploying the coinbase as bytecode. The log0 bytecode should not work. I've no idea why it does work.

Comment: ah, so as I understand it I'm sending the bytecode directly to `eth_sendTransaction` as the data, and regardless of how it's formulated that's how contracts are deployed. Do you by any chance have an example bytecode (written by hand) that could give me a hint on how the bytecode should look to work? I suppose that maybe the log works because it's executing the bytecode to try and deploy the contract but then that doesn't work for obvious reasons.

Comment: also could the fact I'm using `eth_call` instead executing a transaction on the contract be part of the problem?

Comment: The RETURN bytecode is close to a constructor, you have to replace COINBASE with a PUSH `0x4160005260206000f3` and change PUSH 0x20 with the bytecode length (perhaps you need some the padding I can't test now).

Comment: just to be clear, it's okay to send no data when `eth_call`ing the contract address, right? I know for other contracts I had to format the data so that I specified the exact contract method to execute.

Comment: Yes, it's valid to call a contract with an empty data field.

Comment: @ismael I'm still stuck on this, do you mind sharing a code that you know will return 1? i.e. something like `0x600160005260046000f3`. I'm really just interested in something that works so I can begin to investigate the problem. Right now, nothing does and I'm not getting super informative information from debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this in remix and it worked as expected

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    data: “0x684160005260206000f360005260096017f3",
    from: "0x...."})
```

The input data works as follow

```
684160005260206000f3  PUSH 4160005260206000f3 ; payload
6000                  PUSH 0
52                    MSTORE
```

> Save payload starting at 0 memory address. Since it is 9 bytes it will be padded to 32 bytes with zeros.
>
> ```
> address content
> 00      00000000000000000000000000000000
> 10      000000000000004160005260206000f3
> ```
>
> Our payload start at position 23 and its length is 9 bytes, we push the length and offset before RETURN

```
6009                  PUSH 9
6017                  PUSH 23
f3                    RETURN
```

Now we can verify that the deployed contract is the payload

```
> web3.eth.getCode("<Contract_address>")
0x4160005260206000f3
```

Comment: so just to be clear, my code was failing because you actually have to push the bytecode itself onto the stack for it to execute? Do you mind elaborating on why that is / how it relates to the way the evm parses contract deploys? -- I'm a bit confused about why the evm would execute that bytecode but then when you do something like `6041` it doesn't interpret that as saying `push 0x41 on stack and execute COINBASE opcode`; also in the case that the bytecode deployed is greater than 32 bytes how would you deploy that -- considering that the largest PUSH opcode is PUSH32?

Comment: @Alita Contract deployment sequence is specified in Ethereum's Yellow Paper. Your contract failed to execute because the contract deployed wasn't the bytecode you expected but the result of its execution, ie the coinbase address. The sequence 6041 pushes 1 byte 0x41 to the stack and stops because there's no other opcode, whatever is in the stack is never executed. For bytecode longer than 32 bytes CALLDATACOPY is used to copy it to memory.